# Set-AzVMDiagnosticsExtension doesn't work work as expected across subscriptions

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

what I'm trying to is to enable VM Diagnostic extension to send Event logs (Application [1,2,3], Security [all], System [1,2,3]) to one unified storage account (let's call logs storage) where WADWindowsEventLogsTable is supposed to be created.

**different scenarios I'm trying to implement :**

1. VM is in the same resource group where logs storage is.

   **The result :** works
2. VM in a different resource group where logs storage is.

   **The result :** works
3. VM in a different subscription

   **The result :** the extension will be enabled. However, when go to Agent tab, I'll get the error message "the value must not be empty" under Storage account section
   [agent tab, storage account section error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IP9zW.jpg)

**Environment**

Windows

Powershell 7.0.2

**DiagnosticsConfiguration.json**

```
{
"PublicConfig": {
    "WadCfg": {
        "DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration": {
            "overallQuotaInMB": 5120,
            "WindowsEventLog": {
                "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1M",
                    "DataSource": [
                    {
                        "name": "Application!*[System[(Level=1 or Level=2 or Level=3 or Level=4)]]"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Security!*"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "System!*[System[(Level=1 or Level=2 or Level=3 or Level=4)]]"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "StorageAccount": "logsstorage",
    "StorageType": "TableAndBlob"
},
"PrivateConfig": {
    "storageAccountName": "logsstorage",
    "storageAccountKey": "xxxxxxx",
    "storageAccountEndPoint": "https://logsstorage.blob.core.windows.net"
}
}
```

**Powershell commands :**

```
Set-AzVMDiagnosticsExtension -ResourceGroupName "myvmresourcegroup" -VMName "myvm"  -DiagnosticsConfigurationPath "DiagnosticsConfiguration.json"
```

I even tried to explicitly specifying account name and key as :

```
$storage_key = "xxxxxx"
Set-AzVMDiagnosticsExtension -ResourceGroupName "myvmresourcegroup" -VMName "myvm"  -DiagnosticsConfigurationPath "DiagnosticsConfiguration.json" -StorageAccountName "logsstroage" -StorageAccountKey $storage_key
```

I've spent a lot of time trying to figure out the issue without luck.

The real issue here is that the extension doesn't create the expected table **WADWindowsEventLogsTable** (or write to it if it's already exist)

According to the official documentation I should be able to do this, example 3 :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/set-azvmdiagnosticsextension?view=azps-4.3.0

I've submitted an issue with the team on GitHub and gave more details, but still waiting for their input

https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/12259

Comment: I was able to figure it the issue with help from Microsoft engineer. I've updated GitHub issue with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this fixed with some help from Microsoft engineer.

I've detailed the answer in this GitHub issue :

[Set-AzVMDiagnosticsExtension doesn't seem working properly across subscriptions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/12259)

The answer :

I managed to get this work, thanks for the help from @prernavashistha from Microsoft support it turned out there's some inconsistency in the documentations.

According to the documentation here :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/diagnostics-extension-windows-install#powershell-deployment

In **PrivateConfig** I should pass the storage URI to  "storageAccountEndPoint" key :

```
"PrivateConfig": {
"storageAccountEndPoint": "https://logsstorage.blob.core.windows.net"}
```

However, according to another documentation reference :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/diagnostics-extension-schema-windows#json

I should pass the Azure storage endpoint :

```
"PrivateConfig": {
"storageAccountEndPoint": "https://core.windows.net"}
```

I can confirm that using Azure storage endpoint resolved the issue, and I can enable the extension across subscriptions, and I can see logs being written to the correct table as expected.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because the storage account "logsstorage" you specify is in another subscription.

You should have selected a different subscription to enable VM Diagnostic extension. So you also need to modify your `DiagnosticsConfiguration.json` file and specify a storage account which is in the current subscription.

Comment: This is not True. According to the official documentation I should be able to do this. please take a look at Example 3 on this page :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/set-azvmdiagnosticsextension?view=azps-4.3.0

Comment: @Matar You are tight. I only test the first cmd you shared, and it doesn't work for storage account in a different subscription. The second cmd should work for different subscription based on the official document. However, when I test it the cmd is always getting timeout error. There seems to be something wrong with my network environment currently because the first cmd doesn't work neither now. I will keep working on it. If there is any update I will be back.